# Is it possible to create abbreviations in terminal mode?

Tags: vim, neovim

I want to make use of power of abbreviations inside a terminal, I searched for `tabbrev` but it seems to not exists, are there alternatives?

Comment: What do you mean, "inside a terminal"? Do you mean from a shell session? That has nothing to do with `vim` itself.

Comment: If you're asking about a shell session running in a terminal, you need to tell us what shell (and operating system) you're using.  Without that information, we can't provide any assistance.

Comment: Inside a terminal inside vim, I'm running zsh and bash. I'm taking about the :terminal command/mode

Comment: There's `tmap` / `tnoremap`. Obviously, it works like other mapping functions ("delay"), not like abbreviation functions ("space").

Comment: Aliases exist in most shells and are functionally similar to abbreviations, though i recommend functions for maintainability most of the time.

Comment: I use aliases, I search for a way to expand aliases and variables. I was doing some setup and I want to get full command from history, abbreviations expand automatically.

Comment: For linux system wide abbreviations I use autokey, which is powerful and works well

Comment: Ohhhh thanks Floyd, I didn't know that I will take a look